# React-Redux - onClick firing on every state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to removing TodoItem by clicking on TodoItem, but React returns "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.". It is returned because my on click function is called on mount, keyup on input or after clicking Add button and I completely don't know why it works in this way.

App.js (component)

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Header/>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <InputContainer/>
                </div>
                <TodosList todos={this.props.todos}/> {}
            </div>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        todos: state.todos
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

TodosList.js (component)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { TodoItem } from "./TodoItem"
import { handleRemoveTodo } from "./actions"

export class TodosListC extends React.Component{

    todoToTodoItem = todo => {
        return <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} onClick={this.removeTodo(todo.id)}/>
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <ul className='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
                {this.props.todos.map(this.todoToTodoItem)}
            </ul>
        )
    }

    removeTodo = e => {
        this.props.handleRemoveTodo(e);
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        todos: state.todos,
        newInput: state.newInput
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = { handleRemoveTodo };

export const TodosList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodosListC);
```

Todos.js (reducer)

```
export const todos = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'HANDLE_SAVE_VALUE':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
            id: action.id,
            name: action.text
        }
      ]
    case 'HANDLE_REMOVE_TODO':
      //firing on input keyup, click submit button and component mount
      console.log('HANDLE_REMOVE_TODO',action.id)
      var newState = state.filter(function(todo) {
          return action.id !== todo.id
      });
      return[
        newState
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const initState = 
    [{id:99998, name: 'Todo99998'},{id:99999, name:'Todo99999'}]
```

Link to project zip [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxebpjm7bzzlxfi/App.zip?dl=0)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: ` todoToTodoItem = todo => {
        return <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} onClick={() => 
      this.removeTodo(todo.id)}/>
      }` 

this will fix your issue, you should bind the method with fat arrow if you are binding it to onclick event

Comment: ... because `this.removeTodo(todo.id)` actually executes the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned up the code little bit, there was a misconfiguration of mapToProps and unwanted methods, I have removed those this will remove element on click yet you need to fix few stuff in reducer to remove specific data. Best of luck

```js
////TodoListC.js

import * as React from "react";
import {
  connect
} from "react-redux";
import {
  bindActionCreators
} from "redux";
import {
  TodoItem
} from "./TodoItem"
import {
  handleRemoveTodo
} from "./actions"

export class TodosListC extends React.Component {


    render() {
        return ( <
          ul className = 'col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3' > {
            this.props.todos.map((todo) => < TodoItem key = {
                todo.id
              }
              id = {
                todo.id
              }
              todo = {
                todo
              }
              handleRemoveTodo = {
                this.props.handleRemoveTodo
              }
              />)} <
              /ul>
            )
          }


        }

        const mapStateToProps = state => {
          return {
            todos: state.todos,
            newInput: state.newInput
          };
        };

        const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
          handleRemoveTodo
        }, dispatch)

        export const TodosList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodosListC);

////TodoItem.js
import * as React from "react";

export const TodoItem = ({ todo, id, handleRemoveTodo}) => {

 return(
  <li key={id} onClick={() => handleRemoveTodo(id)}>{todo.name}</li>
 )

};
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you guys for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're executing the function on render here

`<TodoItem ... onClick={this.removeTodo(todo.id)}/>`

`onClick` expects a function, but you're calling another function inside of `removeTodo` and returning nothing, so to fix your code you could just re-write it as something like this

`<TodoItem ... onClick={() => this.removeTodo(todo.id)} />`

Answer (score 0):

Update todoToTodoItem method will fix this error :

```js
todoToTodoItem = todo => {
  return <TodoItem key = {
    todo.id
  }
  todo = {
    todo
  }
  onClick = {
    () => this.removeTodo(todo.id)
  }
  />
};
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. I didn't notice I tried this method. It returns no errors but when I click on <li> (TodoItem) unfortunately still do nothing. Why? Log isn't showed.

Comment: @scartout please find my second answer might help you to move forward.